# How do I handle too early observation of LiveData that depend on firebase auth state to be AUTHENTICATED?

Tags: android, firebase, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

In my Fragment's onViewCreated, I have a redirect based on auth state, and also bind the Frag's Observers, like so:

```
class TodoMvvmFragment : Fragment() {
  private val loginViewModel by viewModel<LoginViewModel>()
  private val todoViewModel by viewModel<TodoViewModel>()
  val TAG = "TODO_FRAG"
  var rvAdapter:TodoListAdapter? = null
  var observersBound = false

   ///...omitted

 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    rvAdapter = TodoListAdapter(todoViewModel, this )
    todo_rv.let {
        it.adapter = rvAdapter
        it.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity())
    }

    loginViewModel.authenticationState.observe(this, Observer {
        when(it) {
                LoginViewModel.AuthenticationState.UNAUTHENTICATED -> {
                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_global_loginFragment)
                }
                LoginViewModel.AuthenticationState.AUTHENTICATED -> {
                    // Viewmodel calls aspects of the repository that rely on AUTHSTATE
                    // to be AUTHENTICATED, so don't bind observers until we are.
                    if (!observersBound) {
                        observersBound = true
                        todoViewModel.init()
                        bindObservers()
                        addListeners()
                    }

                }
                else -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, it.toString())
                }

        }
    })




}
```

Here is the problematic Observer:

```
  fun bindObservers() {
    todoViewModel.getFilteredTodos().observe(this, Observer{
        if (it.data == null) {
            handleException("Error with todos by timestamp query", it.exception)
        } else {
            val todos: List<Todo> = it.data.map { todoOrException ->
                if( todoOrException.data == null) {
                    handleException("error with individual Todo", todoOrException.exception)
                    null
                } else {
                    todoOrException.data
                }
            }.filterNotNull()

            rvAdapter?.submitList(todos)
        }
    })
```

This percolates down to the repo, which creates a firebase query.  Notice the .document(auth.uid.toString())...  if this query is created before the user is authorized, no data is returned.

```
fun allTodosQuery(): Query {
    return firestore.collection(PATH_ROOT)
        .document(PATH_APPDATA)
        .collection(PATH_USERS)
        .document(auth.uid.toString())
        .collection(PATH_TODOS)
        .orderBy(FIELD_TIMESTAMP, Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
```

Back in the authentication state listener, I am binding the observers ONLY when auth state changes to authenticated.  I'm also guarding that with a boolean so that it only happens once.  When I don't do that, and just bind the observers in onViewCreated after the auth state listener, I don't get any data on the initial load of the app.

My question is how to keep livedata that depend on authstate being authenticated from omitting nothing when they are bound to before the user is authenticated.  Essentially, how do I keep from fetching a bad query with null auth.uid from the repo before the user is authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for allowing me to rubber duck.  Here's a solution:

```
var _queryResult = Transformations.switchMap(_authState){
    if (_authState.value == LoginViewModel.AuthenticationState.AUTHENTICATED) {
        repo.getAllTodosByTimestamp()
    } else {
        MutableLiveData<ListOrException<TodoOrException>>()
    }
}
```

That way, we don't construct or fire off the query (down in the repo) until authenticated.